# Push forward of a Vector bundle is a coherent sheaf?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth compact Kahler manifold and let $Y\subset X$ be a smooth complex submanifold of complex codimension at least $2$. Let 
$$j:Y\hookrightarrow X$$
the natural (holomorphic) embedding map. Let $E\rightarrow Y$ a holomorphic vector bundle over $Y$. Are there conditions (on $E$, $j$,$Y$,$X$) under which the push forward sheaf $j_{*}E$ is coherent?  Sorry if the question is too standard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is that $j_*E$ is *always* coherent under your hypotheses, provided that $Y$ is closed in $X$.

This is a consequence of the the so-called *Extension Principle*, that can be stated as follows:

> **Proposition.** An analytic sheaf $\mathscr{S}$ on a closed complex subspace $Y$ of a complex space $X$ is $\mathscr{O}_Y$-coherent if and only if the trivial extension of $\mathscr{S}$ to a sheaf on $X$ is $\mathscr{O}_X$-coherent.

In your case $\mathscr{S}=E$, which is a vector bundle, hence a coherent $\mathscr{O}_Y$-sheaf. So the extension $j_*E$ is a coherent $\mathscr{O}_X$-sheaf.

Notice that $X$ and $Y$ are not required to be smooth, and the assumption $\textrm{codim} \, Y \geq 2$ is not necessary.

A reference is Grauert-Remmert, *Coherent Analytic Sheaves*, page 17 and page 239.