# Stability of vector bundles and corresponding coherent sheaf

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, coherent-sheaves

Let $j:Y\hookrightarrow X$ be an embedding of projective complex manifolds. Let $E\rightarrow Y$ be a vector bundle and $S=j_*E$ the corresponding coherent sheaf on $X$ (see [Push forward of a Vector bundle is a coherent sheaf?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/146062/push-forward-of-a-vector-bundle-is-a-coherent-sheaf)).

Assume that $E$ is a stable vector bundle. What can we say about the stability of $S$ as a coherent sheaf on $X$?

Comment: Stability is usually defined for torsion-free sheaves; in your case $S$ is a torsion sheaf.

Comment: If Y is equidimensional, then I believe the pushforward will be a pure sheaf on X. You have notions of stability for pure sheaves on a projective variety, depending on a polarization (choice of ample line bundle). If the polarization that you are using to define stability on Y is the pullback of the polarization that you are using to define stability on X, then I think the (semis)stability of one sheaf is equivalent to the (semi)stability of the pushforward.

Comment: This is because the Hilbert polynomials (resp. generalized slopes) of E and its pushforward will agree, and the pushforward induces an exact bijection between subsheaves of E and subsheaves of the pushforward that preserves Hilbert polynomials (resp. slopes). So E is p-stable (resp. mu-stable)  if and only if the pushforward is.

Comment: @afh can you provide a reference about the behavior of the Hilbert polynomial (or the slope) under pushforward?

Comment: I don't have an exact reference in mind, but one can use the projection formula and the Leray spectral sequence to see that the Hilbert polynomials (and hence generalized slopes) will agree for a closed immersion (or for a finite morphims).